# Trouble with EventListener

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a app which have a button Reset

now this reset button needs to reset all the value to the default value

i have found a example: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/b55Au/2/

But i cant get this working in my Index.cshtml
I was wondering if someone can show me how to get this work in my app, maybe put the function in a .js file and load this .js file in the layout or something?

My index.cshtml class:

```
@{

ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


<script>
    function resetInput1(e) {
        document.getElementById('input1').value = document.getElementById('input1').defaultValue;
    }
    function resetInput2(e) {
        document.getElementById('input2').value = document.getElementById('input2').defaultValue;
    }
    function resetSelect1(e) {
        document.getElementById('select1').value = document.getElementById('select1').selectedIndex = 0;
    }


    document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener('click', resetInput1, true);
    document.getElementById("btn2").addEventListener('click', resetInput2, true);
    document.getElementById("btn3").addEventListener('click', resetSelect1, true);

</script>

<form id="test">
    Input 1: <input type="test" id="input1" value="abcded" /><br><br>

    Input 2: <input type="test" id="input2" value="xyz123" /><br><br>

    Select 1:
    <select id="select1">
        <option selected="selected">Please select...</option>
        <option>Option #1</option>
        <option>Option #2</option>
        <option>Option #3</option>
        <option>Option #4</option>
    </select><br /><br />

    <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Reset Input #1" /><br><br>    
    <input type="button" id="btn2" value="Reset Input #2" /><br><br>    
    <input type="button" id="btn3" value="Reset Select #1" /><br><br>
</form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by default value? The value it has on page load?

Comment: Look at: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/b55Au/2/ 
You have "abcded2" as input1 this is the value on page load. When you edit it to "abcded22323" and click on reset, it will be reset to "abcded2"

Comment: The code is working fine, but i don't know how to place them on the right way in my code to let it work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is analysed before your document has finished loading, this means when it attempts to find the ID's, the elements haven't been created and so no event listeners are added. Either put your  tags underneath the corresponding html or better yet, put it in a external .js file and reference it just before the closing body tag.

Comment: Thanks! This was the answer i was looking for